# How can I be a google OAuth2.0 service provider for non gae applications?

Tags: google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I would like my appengine application to be a **OAuth2.0 Service provider** for the **non gae applications**. I use Google appengine java in my application. I have been searching for long time but I am not getting enough documentation.

Comment: Try asking a question

Answer (score 0):

What type of consumer applications would you like to support? Would these be mobile applications (Android, iOS) or other web apps? And are these other apps also developed by you /  your organization or by other parties?

Comment: I would like to support other non google appengine web applications which are developed by other parties. I have been consumer to those applications but, Now I would like to be a Service provider.